# How to make a Read the Docs Project Version Public again

Tags: read-the-docs

A few weeks ago, I made one of the RTD documentation versions I'm working on private, because that version was still in alpha state. Now is the time to make the documentation public again, because we are getting that version ready for release

For some reason, however, it now seems impossible to switch that private version back to public.

Here's the list of versions where you can see 5.0 is marked Private:

[image: View of versions]

When editing 5.0, however, there is no option to make it public again. Here's a screen capture of that edit screen:

[image: Editing 5.0]

I tried changing "Active" and "Hidden", even wiped 5.0, and went through the complete Admin menu, Googled, and read the RTD documentation to figure out how to make that version Public again, without success.

How can I switch the 5.0 branch to public and change the branch that a version points at?

Comment: are you using the free version of read the docs, readthedocs.org , or read the docs for business, readthedocs.com?

Comment: I'm using the free version.

Comment: How did you initially make it private? I thought privacy levels were only available on the paid version https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/versions.html#privacy-levels

Comment: Good question. Perhaps that's the reason I can't turn it public again. Not sure though how I made it private. Although I'm not sure since it's a few weeks ago,, I think there was a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a glitch in RTD, during the process of deprecating the privacy levels and supported this via hidden attributes. RTD missed this in their migration. They set it to public after having email contact with them.